# wait until current media finish playing before it play another in android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Here is my media player code in android. My problem is the loop plays all the files from the zipfolder without waiting for the current to finish playing. How do I solve this problem. I am quite new to android doing my first project ! Need some expert help.

//code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button playButton;
    private MediaPlayer mp;    
    private static final String MAIN_TAG ="ERROR";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         try {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        //final String file_loc= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        //Log.i("location",file_loc);
             ZipFile zip = new ZipFile("/storage/emulated/0/AjeshDocument/sample.zip");

             for(int i=1;i<9;i++){

             ZipEntry entry = zip.getEntry("sample/rihanna_"+i+".mp3");                        
             if (entry != null) {
                 InputStream in = zip.getInputStream(entry);
                 // see Note #3.
                 File tempFile = File.createTempFile("_AUDIO_", ".wav");
                 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
                 IOUtils.copy(in, out);

                 // do something with tempFile (like play it)
                 File f = tempFile;   
                 try {
                     if (f.exists())
                     {
                         Log.i(MAIN_TAG,"Audio file found!");
                         MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
                         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                         mp.setDataSource(fis.getFD());

                      //  if (mp.isPlaying() == false) {                        
                         mp.prepare();
                         //mp.setLooping(false);
                         mp.start();                         
                        // mp.stop();
                         //mp.release();

                         mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                             public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp2) {
                                 mp2.release();

                             };
                         });
                      // }  
                         Log.i(MAIN_TAG,"Song finished!");
                     }  


                   else
                     {
                         Log.i(MAIN_TAG,"File doesn't exist!!");
                     }

                 }
                 catch (IOException e)
                 {
                     Log.i(MAIN_TAG,e.toString());
                 }
             }
             else {
                 // no such entry in the zip
             }
            } //for end
            // mp.release();

         }  
             catch (Exception e) {
             // handle your exception cases...

             Log.i(MAIN_TAG,e.toString());

         }       

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.w("Info", "App Resume");

        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.w("Info", "App stopped");

        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.w("Info", "App destoryed");

        super.onDestroy();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're creating a new mp instance for each song. Firstly, you should create a Song class to hold the song information. Alternately, you can just create a list of Strings containing the filepaths to the songs. Then, you can do something like this:

```
int playlistPos = 0;

protected void onCreate(Bundled savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initSong(songs.get(playlistPos);
    mp.start();

    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        playlistPos++;
        initSong(songs.get(playlistPos);
        mp.start();
    });
}

private void initSong(Song song) {
    // Set the datasource in here, prepare, etc
}
```

Once each song finishes, it will move the playlistPos along by one, and start the player again.