# Play all media files from zip folder in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have the same requirement to play media files  in android media player as explained in below thread link.

[Can Android MediaPlayer play audio in a zipped file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900249/can-android-mediaplayer-play-audio-in-a-zipped-file)

It has explained how to play media files from the zip folder. My extra requirement is to play all the files in zip folder sequentially and files can also have video  . How can I do this ? I am very new to android . Need some help.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried and what specific problems you encountered.

Comment: I have tried playing all files in zip folder (only audio now) . But i am facing issue that it doesn't wait for current to finish. Here is my another question I have asked in stackoverflow and I am still not clear how to implement the solution .

[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856163/wait-until-current-media-finish-playing-before-it-play-another-in-android/23856215#23856215